# PHP PDO Declare name as variable

Tags: php, variables, pdo

So In my project I'm trying to declare a variable so it will display their full name if logged in. I'm assuming it would be a query to fetch the data from the table but I'm unsure on how to have it make sure it get's that certain user's name and not the first name on the table

Here's my registration code.

```
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); }
```

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
//very basic validation
if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['username'])){
        $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
    }

}

if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
}

if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
}

if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
    $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
}

//email validation
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
        $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
    }

}
    //email validation
if(strlen($_POST['fullname']) < 2){
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid full name';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT fullname FROM members WHERE fullname = :fullname');
    $stmt->execute(array(':fullname' => $_POST['fullname']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
        $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
    }

}

//if no errors have been created carry on
if(!isset($error)){

    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    //create the activasion code
    $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

    try {

        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,fullname,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :fullname, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':fullname' => $_POST['fullname'],
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

        //send email
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
        $body = "Thank you for registering at demo site.\n\n To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n ".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion\n\n Regards Site Admin \n\n";
        $additionalheaders = "From: <".SITEEMAIL.">\r\n";
        $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: $".SITEEMAIL."";
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: index.php?action=joined');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

}

Updated with the user class:

```
<?php
```

include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

```
private $_db;

function __construct($db){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $db;
}

private function get_user_hash($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['password'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}

public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }   
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your login method, save `$username` as a session value under `$_SESSION['loggedin']` that you can retrieve later like this...

```
public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Then have another method at the bottom of the file that goes something like...

```
public function get_username(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
       return $_SESSION['username'];
    }
}
```

Then you can call this method like $user->get_username() to get the current logged in users username. Then getting their fullname from the database would require a simple query with "WHERE username = :username". I you can add another method like this to make things easier...

```
 public function get_fullname(){
    if(issset($_SESSION['username']){
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT fullname FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $this->get_fullname()));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['fullname'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the original post with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply select them from the database?

Please don't mind me if I mix in  a little pseudo code since I'm not very familiar with your variables.

First, you create/start a SESSION if the login credentials are correct.

```
if($login_credentials_correct){ //lol you know what I mean here
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // or wherever it may have come from
}
```

Now that the session is on, you can perform a query somewhat similar to this

```
<?php

  session_start(); // fixed

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT fullname FROM members where username= :username');

  $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $fullName = $row['fullName']; //I am not sure if this is the correct index.
  //to make sure, use var_dump($row) and find out which index has the full name
  echo $fullName; //voila.
?>
```

Now, this code only works if your username is unique. Lol. which site has no unique username.

Comment: I get this error.     'Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(18): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18'

Comment: It means you have not started the session in the next page

Comment: You have to do session_start() again before using $_SESSION again. editing the answer again. sorry.It should work this time. :)

Comment: I already did that, Proof: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Can you please comment in lines number 15-20 in index.php?

Comment: Commented it out and get this. Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: fullname in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 28

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your log in code? I'll try to answer with what you ave so far.
If you want users to have the ability to log in and have their data available for display do this

```
  if(!($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")){
     //Code here for users trying to access page incorrectly
  }else{

     if(isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['username'] <= $UsernameMaxLength)){
       $username=strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['username'])); //Clean the data up
     }else{
       //Error handling code
     }

     if(isset($_POST['password']) && ($_POST['password'] <= $PasswordMaxLength)){
       //I would advise you use SHA1() instead for password encryption, but I'll use what you used here
       $password=$user->password_hash(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['password'])), PASSWORD_BCRYPT); //Clean the data up
     }else{
       //Error handling code
     }

     if(!isset($username) || !isset($password)){
        //Error handling code
     }else{
         $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT fullname FROM members where username= :username and password=:password');

         $stmt->execute(array('username':$username,'password':$password));
         $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         //Code here to make sure there is a row with the number given and all that 
         //other jazz. In this code I'll assume all went well
         if(All_went_well){
            //Start your session to store variables you want
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['fullname']=$row['fullname'];
          }

     }

  }
```